# Magento2 - plugin / event after invoice is created

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer, invoice, plugin

I need to execute some custom code after invoice is created

I have some code working fine, when invoices are created in admin storeview (I am observing **sales_order_save_before** event & checking for a state change to detect if the invoice has been created), but this does not work when 3rd party payment methods create the invoice during frontend checkout process

I am not sure if I can achieve this with observer / event approach, or maybe a plugin should be the right method. Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried using this event on the front end? this shoul give you the result your looking for no matter the gateway sales_order_invoice_save_after

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved this using **sales_order_invoice_pay** event, which is fired both in admin & frontend scopes

Comment: Thanks it work. but when use 'sales_order_invoice_pay' event i am not able to get invoice id or increment id can you help how can i get invoice id.

Comment: Yes, when using this event no invoice id or increment id is getting. Any solution for this?

Comment: If you need Invoice ID then you maybe want to observe after_save event: sales_order_invoice_save_after

Comment: @RaulSanchez  i am using sales_order_invoice_save_after but no luck, can you suggest further

Comment: You'd better create a question for this @vinit